# What's off-topic?

Tags: discussion

There are a few questions so far that seem open-ended or otherwise kind of off-topic. While I don't want to be a buzz-kill, it seems like it may make sense to provide some guidance.

Here's one that seems unlikely to ever get a really solid answer: [What's an easy-to-use tool to manage datasets?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/29/whats-an-easy-to-use-tool-to-manage-datasets) (although it has 4 upvotes at this moment)

This one was also a little suspect to me: [Is there a list of all utilities that offer the Green Button Download and Green Button Connect?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-there-a-list-of-all-utilities-that-offer-the-green-button-download-and-green)

More generally, what's the right way to advance this question about specific posts? Should there be separate meta-posts for each question under question? or...?

Comment: I think some of the data-hunt question are a somewhat off-topic. I did though answer the Green Button question and, in doing so, discovered how freakin' buried the FAQ and explanatory resources were. 

I think the "easy-to-use" is definitely subjective and doesn't lend itself to the expected "best" answer. But within the body of the question there is more meat, so I'm giving that a pass as well. I think we need more time.

Comment: Concerning the *best answer*, I think before generate a discussion if it is on-topic or not, the correct path would be to suggest a question rephrase.

Comment: I find it very helpful to be able to ask and learn about the uses of open data. This is quite important to publishers of open data, in order to measure the impact or ROI on investing in publishing data sets. I'd recommend keeping these in scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a new meta question for each different kind of "off-topicness" whenever the need arises.

Examples: [Programming / database questions with no clear Open Data focus](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/programming-database-questions-with-no-clear-open-data-focus), [Are real time information systems on-topic?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-real-time-information-systems-on-topic), [Is data collection on-topic?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-data-collection-on-topic), [Are graph visualization/tools on-topic here?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/are-graph-tools-on-topic-here), ...

Otherwise, the discussions in this question thread will probably become confusing really fast.

Comment: I agree. But don't try to anticipate *toooo many* problems before they actually occur on the site. The last thing you want is a premeditated series of "all the things you can do wrong on this site." The occasional hypothetical is okay, but it's best to use specific posts as an occasion to discuss the bigger scope issues.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I completely agree :)