# Are graph visualization/tools on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I asked [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/93/graph-visualization-analysis-tool) concerning tools to visualize and analyse graphs.

Following the suggestion of Dmitry Kachaev, I would be interesting to discuss if this kind of question is on-topic.

Despite of visualization tools are more related to data in general, open data is a particular case of data and sometimes it is necessary to visualize it, so **why not**?

*From **my perspective**, anything related to Open Data is on-topic, that includes seek, process, visualize, legal/license concernings, etc.*

Comment: Echoing Patrick Hoefler's answer, I would recommend changing the question to use 'chart' rather than 'graph', or otherwise clarifying that you'er talking about data visualization and not graph theory.

Comment: I think the question isn't ambiguous about that. The question has nothing to do with graphs but a recommendation of a graph visualization tool (that obviously is going to draw graphs as diagrams)

Comment: the word 'graph' is ambiguous. The word 'chart' is not. I'm merely talking about changing the headline question which a person would see in a list view, where the detail of the question is not available to clarify the intention.

Comment: @JoeGermuska I don't see any ambiguity in the question, but fell free to improve it ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. Nevertheless, if the edit button weren't disabled for this question, I'd simply change it to 'Are graph viz/analysis tools on topic here?'

Comment: @JoeGermuska ah... lol! We were talking about different question, I was thinking in the original question, not this meta-question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graphs and graph tools are absolutely on topic for the Open Data SE, since graph structures are becoming an important way to represent data in a interconnected world.

Quick note though: "Graph" in this context means the [mathematical graphs with nodes and edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), not [charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart) or [diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram). This could really lead to confusion, especially with regard to tagging. My proposal would be to use [graph](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) or [graphs](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) for graph structures and [chart](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chart), [charts](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charts) or [charting](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charting) for graphs in the sense of charts or diagrams.

Comment: The usual way to visualize graphs is with diagrams, actually when one is creating a graph it is usually with a [diagram representation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/6n-graf.svg/333px-6n-graf.svg.png)

Comment: @RSFalcon7, you're absolutely right. What I meant to say is that people sometimes use "graph" to refer to charts or diagrams, and this is where things start to get confusing ;)

Comment: maybe the tag `[node-edge-graph]` should be used instead of `[graph]`. I know it's stupid and mathematicians won't like it, but it prevents misunderstanding! The tag wiki should be filled in of course, but I think the tag name should be unambigous by itself, as many people won't read the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This question might fit better at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

But be sure to include more detailed requirements, for instance:

- the format of your data
- whether you want an off-the-shelf tool or a library
- what is your budget

We can't help you efficiently if we don't know your requirements.