# Are real time information systems on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I wrote [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/111/is-there-any-world-wide-real-time-catastrophe-information-system) about real time catastrophes information systems.

The definition if this question should be on-topic it is probably important since it brings to the table a ***new*** (given the present questions on the site) **type of open data**: real time open data.

Answer (score 6):

Open real-time data is definitely something that we'll see a lot more of in the not-too-distant future. Therefore, it is not just on-topic, but very relevant to the Open Data SE. One nice example would be the [London public transportation real-time data](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/businessandpartners/syndication/16493.aspx) provided by Transport for London.

Comment: I agree.  Many of the popular datasets on Data.gov are those that are provided in real-time or near-real-time (such as earthquake data for the last 7 days: https://explore.data.gov/Geography-and-Environment/Worldwide-M1-Earthquakes-Past-7-Days/7tag-iwnu) (Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist with Data.gov)