# What programming questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I see that a [recent question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/historical-weather-data-need-to-month-wise-instead-of-day-wise) about the wundergroud.com API has been deleted (*EDIT : was voluntarily removed by its author*), probably because it was better suited for StackOverflow. In going through Open Data Meta, it's still not clear for me what programming questions are on topic. For example, the majority of answers on [this thread](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/are-webscraping-data-on-topic) seem to consider web scraping questions as on topic. So, why not API questions ?

The StackOverflow community can be very harsh with newbies or non-programmers... Is there no room, here, for basic programming issues related to data-requests ?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the [linked question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/historical-weather-data-need-to-month-wise-instead-of-day-wise) was voluntarily removed by its author. Also, our [on-topic help page](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) currently recommends "Stack Overflow for programming questions without a clear focus on open data".

Comment: @PatrickHoefler Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that I also consulted the help center. But I still had a doubt, since the word "programming" doesn't appear directly in the list "If you have a question about …"
In addition, there is very little code in the questions and answers I've  read so far, even those with the keywords `programming`or `python`. I'm glad that this type of question is accepted. Maybe the user we are talking about also had a doubt and, thus, deleted his question.

Comment: i feel the exact opposite; if its regarding getting access to open data, making data open, etc., it qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

In the very instance you rightly pointed in your question above, the [post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/historical-weather-data-need-to-month-wise-instead-of-day-wise) was voluntarily removed by its author, just as you mentioned, probably for reasons best known to him/her, perhaps, to attract more and or faster contributions.

It is **not** to say that programming questions are automatically off-topic on Open Data Stack Exchange (ODSE).

On the ODSE help page for [on-topic](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) posts it reads: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for programming questions without a clear focus on open data.

What is important to note here is that programming questions are welcomed on ODSE provided they relate to open data.

There is room, within the acceptable frame of ODSE and this is not to say that spoon-feeding is encouraged but efforts at resolving ones challenge rather than expecting the community to *teach* instead of *assisting*.